# Understanding crash for reading KERN_MEMORY_ERROR address pointed to memory mapped file

Tags: macos, debugging, crash, mmap, lmdb

I'm trying to figure out how does reading from mmapped file can trigger KERN_MEMORY_ERROR if the address reside within the memory borders.

Here's an example for one such crash, where trying to read from lmdb formatted file (possibly corrupted). It can clearly be seen that the invalid address reside inside the `mapped file` region which is the lmdb mapped file.

Thus, any attempt to access address within the mapped range can either retrieve the page contents directly from memory, or trigger page fault trap that eventually lead to reading the missing data from disk and return it to process as well.

One thing that raise some concerns is that the file size is only 24k and the mapping spans over 256M. However, the file's meta data seems to be coherent to file contents.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_MEMORY_ERROR at 0x000000010648800a
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x10648800a:

__LINKEDIT             0000000106464000-000000010647f000 [  108K] r--/rwx SM=COW  ^Z^C [/usr/lib/dyld]
--> mapped file        000000010647f000-000000011647f000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  Object_id=9034edd9
STACK GUARD            000070000f2b3000-000070000f2b4000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   myprog                     0x0000000101666756 mdb_page_search_root + 39
1   myprog                     0x00000001016660f7 mdb_page_search + 182
2   myprog                     0x00000001016614de mdb_cursor_set + 88
3   myprog                     0x0000000101661476 mdb_get + 134
```